Groups in circular permutations
Let's say that there are $4$ entities: $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ that are to be permutated around a round table. There are $(4-1)!$ permutations for them to be seated. However, if $A$ and $B$ were a couple, why is the number of permutations now $(3-1)!$? Shouldn't it be still $(4-1)!$, since there are still $4$ seats?

Are you sure the number of permutation is $(3-1)!$? I believe you're missing another multiplier / product / coefficient.

Yeah, there should be a factor of $2!$

If there are $4$ entries, the number of arrangements in $(4-1)!$.
If $A$ and $B$ are couple, it may mean that $A$ and $B$ are always together. In that case, take $A$ and $B$ both as a "group" and count the number of circular permutations which is $(3-1)!$, but $A$ and $B$ can rearrange between themselves in $2!$ ways, so the number of arrangements is $2!\cdot(3-1)!$
Though there are still $4$ seats, we are only accounting the cases where $A$ and $B$ are together and not when $A$ and $B$ are not together. So, the number of permutations vary in the two cases.
